# What is the meaning of "il y a de quoi flairer les bonnes affaires"?

Tags: sens

- Dans un pays déchiré par la crise et où tout se vend, **il y a de quoi flairer les bonnes affaires**.

I cannot fully understand this phrase. Does it mean "there's room for sniffing out good deals"?

Answer (score 2):

"Flairer une bonne affaire" means "to feel there is an opportunity for a good deal".

"Il y a de quoi" + verb means "there is what is needed for", or "there are good reasons for".

Ex:

"Avec ces résultats, il y a de quoi s'inquiéter" : "with those results, there are good reasons for being nervous/there is definitely something to be worried about"

"Regarde dans le frigo, il y a de quoi manger" : "look in the fridge, there is something to eat"

Or also in the negative turn:

"n'aie pas peur, il n'y a pas de quoi s'inquiéter" : "don't be afraid, there is nothing to be worried about"

"tu as fait une bêtise, il n'y a pas de quoi être fier" : "you've made a blunder, there is nothing to be proud of"

So in this context "il y a de quoi flairer les bonnes affaires" means that there are good reasons to find out opportunities for some good deals.

(a side note: you also find the phrase "il y a de quoi" + verb to understate that there is actually even a lot. Ex: "j'ai l'intention faire du jardinage ce weekend: il y a de quoi faire !" "I'm planning to do some gardening next weekend: there is a lot to do !")